# Cross-targeting frameworks with NuGet 4.0 and Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, msbuild-4.0, visual-studio-2017

I am having a rough time figuring out how to setup cross-targeting inside a Visual Studio 2017 project and I have not been able to find any examples.

I started out with a .NET Standard 1.5 project and to keep it simple I am just trying to add .NET Standard 1.6.  If I understand the documentation correctly, I should now be able to do all of this inside the csproj file without having to mess with a project.json or nuspec file.

I've tried all of these values but none seem to work:

```
<TargetFrameworks>netstandard15;netstandard16</TargetFrameworks>
<TargetFrameworks>netstandard1.5;netstandard1.6</TargetFrameworks>
<TargetFrameworks>.NETStandard,Version=v1.5;.NETStandard,Version=v1.6</TargetFrameworks>
```

This is the only source of documentation I can find on the feature and it doesn't contain a full example:

https://docs.nuget.org/ndocs/schema/msbuild-targets

https://docs.nuget.org/ndocs/create-packages/supporting-multiple-target-frameworks

Comment: Nobody has discussed about multi targeting in MSBuild for .NET Core projects yet IMHO. You have to target a single platform right now, unless Microsoft gives more info. The docs you referred to are NuGet only and I don't think they are relevant.

Comment: AH!  Yes, that makes total sense.  I don't know how it got stuck in my head that MSBuild would recognize tags used by NuGet.  Thank you for politely answering such a stupid question.

Comment: Well, I believe you have asked a very good question, but not at a right time. Microsoft just brought MSBuild support back to .NET Core, and shipped a preview build with VS2017. So it is not known yet how multiple frameworks in `project.json` should be translated to MSBuild syntax. Time will tell.

Comment: This is still a good question. Half a year later there still doesn't seem to be an answer?

Answer (score 2):

I've gotten this to work on latest Visual Studio 2017. As described in this post https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/10/19/net-core-tooling-in-visual-studio-15/ it is the correct way to do it. My csproj file looks like this:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <TargetFrameworks>netstandard1.6;net452</TargetFrameworks>
</PropertyGroup>
```

[Visual Studio 2017 RC release notes](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/releasenotes/vs2017-relnotes) also has this listed as a feature (under .NET Core and Docker):

- Cross-target multiple target frameworks in one project.

My mistake at the start was that when I first created the project the property was called `TargetFramework`, I tried to add multiple targets and VS did not like that at all. It just crashes then... So make sure to rename it to `TargetFrameworks` and it should work.